# Swifty JSON Not Working After Updating to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swifty-json

my `JSON` Respose is

```
{
    code = 1;
    document =     (
                {
            Address1 = "<null>";
            Address2 = "<null>";
            City = "<null>";
            CompanyID = 1;
            CompanyName = Innohabit;
            ContactNumber = "<null>";
            Designation = "<null>";
            DesignationID = 36;
            DesignationName = dev;
            Email = "uday.mishra@Gmail.com";
            FCMRegistrationToken = "";
            GCMRegistrationToken = "";
            Gender = Male;
            ID = 9;
            IsActive = 1;
            IsFirstLogin = 1;
            LastLogin = "2016-09-21 05:45:33";
            Name = "Uday Mishra";
            Password = "";
            ProfilePic = "";
            RegisterationDate = "2016-03-04 07:42:42";
            UserTwitter = "<null>";
            Username = "uday.mishra@Gmail.com";
        }
    );
    message = "Record found";
    status = success;
}
```

And Trying to Convert the respose using `Swifty Json` Like this

```
            case .success:
            print(response)

            let jsonResponse = JSON(response.data)
            print("JSON")
            let jsonData = jsonResponse["document"]
            print(jsonResponse)
            print(jsonData[0])
```

But I am Not getting the desired result, the Output is

```
{
    code = 1;
    document =     (
                {
            Address1 = "<null>";
            Address2 = "<null>";
            City = "<null>";
            CompanyID = 1;
            CompanyName = Innohabit;
            ContactNumber = "<null>";
            Designation = "<null>";
            DesignationID = 36;
            DesignationName = dev;
            Email = "uday.mishra@Gmail.com";
            FCMRegistrationToken = "";
            GCMRegistrationToken = "";
            Gender = Male;
            ID = 9;
            IsActive = 1;
            IsFirstLogin = 1;
            LastLogin = "2016-09-21 05:45:33";
            Name = "Uday Mishra";
            Password = "";
            ProfilePic = "";
            RegisterationDate = "2016-03-04 07:42:42";
            UserTwitter = "<null>";
            Username = "uday.mishra@Gmail.com";
        }
    );
    message = "Record found";
    status = success;
}
JSON
unknown
null
```

As u can see the response is getting printed ,but the **print(jsonResponse)** and  **print(jsonData[0])**
is printing  **Unknown** and **null** can anyone help me how i can serialise the data properly into `JSON` format from `DataRespose`

please suggest any alternative method or if I m doing any mistake please help me.

Comment: pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/appsailor/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'

Comment: i m using the same thing in my pod file

Comment: Still not Getting please help.

Comment: Is there any alternative.

Comment: Have you tried SwiftJSON?

Comment: @uday your swift version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it is working fine for me.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post,parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    //print(response)

                    let jsonResponse = JSON(data)
                    print("JSON")
                    let jsonData = jsonResponse["document"][0]
                    print("Email")
                    print(jsonData["Email"])



                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
```

Comment: My friend "Alamofire" already working. You want solution in SwiftyJson.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bellow code :

```
if let jsonResponse: AnyObject = JSON(response.data){   
    let jsonData = jsonResponse["document"]
    print(jsonResponse)
    print(jsonData[0])
}
```

**Edit:**

I read below statement on [this](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/200)

> The platform of the target Pods (iOS 7.1) is not compatible with SwiftyJSON (2.1.3) which has a minimum requirement of OS X 10.9 - iOS 8.0.
>   EDIT:
>   I replaced SwiftyJson.swift with the one in Xcode 6.3 branch and it worked fine now no errors. :-)

So try to follow that step.

Comment: I am getting Error :- Cannot downcast from 'JSON' to a more optional type '[String : AnyObject]!'